# How to Send Large File From Client To Server Using WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, stream, large-files

How to Send Large File From Client To Server Using WCF in C#? Below the configuration code.

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="HttpStreaming_IStreamingSample" 
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
                          transferMode="Streamed">
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint 
            address="http://localhost:4127/StreamingSample.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="HttpStreaming_IStreamingSample"
            contract="StreamingSample.IStreamingSample" 
            name="HttpStreaming_IStreamingSample" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: OK,this is the client config. Please also show server config, and the service contract (what does your method look like that you're calling?)

Answer (score 6):

You need to check out streaming, as Dzmitry already pointed out.

In order to be able to send large files as a stream to your service, you'll need to:

- create a service method that accepts a `Stream` as its input parameter
- create a binding configuration (on both the server and the client) which uses `transferMode=StreamedRequest`
- create a stream in your client and send it to the service method

So first off, you need a method in your service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IYourFileService
{
   [OperationContract]
   void UploadFile(Stream file)
}
```

Then you need a binding configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="FileUploadConfig"
             transferMode="StreamedRequest" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and a service endpoint on your service using that binding configuration:

```
<services>
  <service name="FileUploadService">
     <endpoint name="UploadEndpoint"
               address="......."
               binding="basicHttpBinding"
               bindingConfiguration="FileUploadConfig"
               contract="IYourFileService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

and then, in your client, you need to open e.g. a filestream and send that to the service method without closing it.

Hope that helps!

Marc

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have already tried this,but it throws the following exception "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

Comment: that sounds like something with your config is not okay - can you post client and server config that you have now in your original questions? Just the <system.serviceModel> sections. Thanks!

Comment: <basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="HttpStreaming" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="Buffered">
</binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

  <service name="WCFFileStreamingDemo.StreamingSample" behaviorConfiguration="WCFFileStreamingDemo.StreamingSampleBehavior">
       <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName="HttpStreaming"  contract="WCFFileStreamingDemo.IStreamingSample">         
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>

Comment: I'm assuming this throws interoperability out the window?

Comment: @fireworks: yes, from all I know and all you can find online, http-based streaming in WCF is definitely **not** interoperable, e.g. only works between two .NET WCF endpoints.

Comment: @marc_s Thank for your good answer. I read the article in MSDN : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-enable-streaming and I want to know that can my method has several parameters as input ? Or it should has just and only one `Stream` param? Can I have this method `void Upload(Stream stream, string username, DateTime date)?`

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [WCF Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) feature.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to increasing readerQuota settings (mentioned above) I had to also up the maxRequestLength inside the httpRuntime attribute.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
```