# Client memory usage on WCF web service with large data

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming, large-data

I have a WCF web service which needs to returns a file (Can be returned by a byte array or by streaming). I was first returning a byte[] in the interface, which caused the client to go up to a **400MB** memory usage (at peak) for a **100MB** file.
Since I need to reduce the client memory usage, I've added another interface which streams the file back to the client. This time, I witness a **600MB** increase in the client (again, in peak). How can I reduce the client memory usage?

My current implementation of the server is as follows (streaming):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOmriService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetAudio(string input);
}
```

App.config:

```
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="HttpStreaming" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="Streamed"/>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519512/how-to-send-large-file-from-client-to-server-using-wcf   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030137/large-binary-byte-file-transfer-through-wcf

Comment: I already read these posts and they suggest nothing different. My only issue is the RAM usage at the client side

Comment: Your client is receiving a large file ? during the data transfer, where does the client store the data ? if it receive 600MB file, and not saving in by chunks to the disc, it will remain in process memory no ?

Comment: The client gets a 100MB file and keeps it memory. The problem is that the client memory usage comes up to 400MB at peak before reducing to around 100MB.

Comment: maybe this could help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of doing it in WCF.
What I did was using a "simple" http file download. This consumes almost no memory by the client.